# circular scrollview in Android

Tags: android

I want to make a scrollview with images and when reaches the end come back to the beginning. just like a picture gallery.

Someone have any idea?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom adapter by extending `BaseAdapter` class and implementing its methods by a circular data structure that you have in your mind.

for working with custom adapters, use these:

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/

hope that help :)